# Why does mutating a passed Option inside a function not propagate to the Option outside?

Tags: rust, move-semantics, mutability

I've illustrated it thus:

```
fn main() {

    let mut opt1 = Some(1);
    // compiler complains that opt2 doesn't have to be mutable
    let mut opt2 = Some(1);

    fn take_inner(mut opt: Option<u8>) {
        opt.take();
    };

    opt1.take();
    take_inner(opt2);

    println!("opt1 {:?}", opt1); // prints "opt1 None"
    println!("opt2 {:?}", opt2); // prints "opt2 Some(1)"

}
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c59dea1a1c1f6eccdb0240d8338ed1fe&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Why does calling `opt.take()` within a function have a different effect than calling it outside (relative to the main function's scope)?

Comment: My motivation is that I want to offload some option mutation into an explicit routine, but now it seems like I'd need a macro for that. Am I right?

Comment: Option implement Copy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `u8` is a copy type, and `Option` has

```
impl<T> Copy for Option<T>
where
    T: Copy,
```

`take_inner` takes a copy of `opt2`

You can fix that by taking a mutable reference:

```
fn main() {
    let mut opt1 = Some(1);
    // compiler complains that opt2 doesn't have to be mutable
    let mut opt2 = Some(1);

    fn take_inner(opt: &mut Option<u8>) {
        opt.take();
    };

    opt1.take();
    take_inner(&mut opt2);

    println!("opt1 {:?}", opt1);
    println!("opt2 {:?}", opt2);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4809b90b3fce0064b8f006ff006bcb57&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 5):

When `T: Copy` then so is `Option<T>`. This means that, when you pass it as a function argument:

```
take_inner(opt2);
```

it actually will copy the data. If `T` was not `Copy` then none of this would even work because the value would instead be *moved*, so you could not even print it later.

If you pass it as a mutable reference, then the function can change the original value:

```
fn take_inner(opt: &mut Option<u8>) {
    opt.take();
};

take_inner(&mut opt2);
```